# Disable a field form based on another field in rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I don't have an error in my project, only i can't find a solution for my problem. I will be grateful if you help me.

I have a form with two fields:

```
<%= f.select  :role, { "admin" => 1, "writer" => 2, "guest" => 3} %>
<%= f.text_area :about %>
```

I want disable text_area field when i select "guest" parameter in role field. i want do it without JavaScript, can i do it with rails feature?

Comment: why can't you apply the js there?

Comment: You need to use js in this case unless you are checking with value obtained from controller.

Comment: If Rails has this ability  So why  use the JavaScript?

Answer (score 1):

To do this you must use javascript. There is no other way.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: Happy to delete this and add it as a comment, but I would have seen this as an answer? The answer to the question is "no". I'm not asking for clarification from the author - the question is "i want do it without JavaScript, can i do it with rails feature?" and the answer is "no, you must use javascript".

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to use java-script then you have to submit then form on select change and need to save all the things and set :disabled => true when form load on the text area based on the whatever condition you want.

Comment: Submitting the form on select change requires javascript.

Comment: Yes submitting form needs javascript, If no javascript on the page then  there are no way I think.(I assumed Zakaria do not want to disable text area only by javascript)